# How to assign value to radio button in Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, angular-ui

How to assign JSON value to below radio button (Unlimited,Custom) . ?
I have  added `[(ngModel)]="user.accessSchedule.fullAccess"`  it. But it is not working.

```
<ol-radio-group [selected]="unlimitedAccessSchedule" id="accessSchedule"  [(ngModel)]="user.accessSchedule.fullAccess"  name="accessSchedule" orientation="horizontal">
   <ol-radio #unlimitedAccessSchedule value="true" id="unlimitedAccessSchedule" class="col-sm-4">
       Unlimited
   </ol-radio>
   <ol-radio #customAccessSchedule value="false" id="customAccessSchedule" class="col-sm-4 with-subform">
       Custom
   </ol-radio>
</ol-radio-group>
```

Below is JSON

```
"user": {
   "accessSchedule": {
     "fullAccess": true,
     "accessSchedule": [],
     "holdDateRange": null,
     "userAccessScheduleVersion": null
  }
 }
```

Comment: What does the documentation of those ol- components say? Where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

In Normal html code using Radio button true or false selected :

```
<input type="radio" name="fullAccess" [(ngModel)]="user.accessSchedule.fullAccess" [value]="true">

<input type="radio" name="fullAccess" [(ngModel)]="user.accessSchedule.fullAccess" [value]="false">


"user": {
   "accessSchedule": {
     "fullAccess": true,
     "accessSchedule": [],
     "holdDateRange": null,
     "userAccessScheduleVersion": null
  }
 }
```